# Appium :Click on capture image button of inbuilt camera in mobile app. is it possible?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, android, android-automation

Appium(Android) :Click on capture image button of inbuilt camera in mobile app. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure yes but I do have a trick I have used in the past. So, you'll want to open the Appium Inspector session. If you can find the selector then you're off to a good start. If the element is "not intractable" you can use the selector to get the size and location. From that you can derive where to `Tap(x,y)`.